# Preventing database results from poping up when writing into a form

Tags: php

So I have live results system (When you type into the form, it will find live results and open a list dropdown).

```
 /**
 The search suggestion START
 **/
    $(document).ready(function () {
        list = $(".menus");
        form = $("#search");
        form.keyup(function () {
            if (form.val() !== '') {
                load();
                $.post("ajax_suggestions.php", { search : form.val() }, function(data) {
                    list.slideDown("slow");
                    list.html(data);
                    unload();
                });
            } else {
                list.slideUp("slow");
                unload();
            }
        });
    });



    function load() {
        $("#loading").show();
    }
    function unload() {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
```

**Problem:**

When I type something into that form, the list opens but, the results from my cache I've searched before, pop up.

How do I prevent this from happening? how can I disable cache results for this form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In html you one attribute called

```
autocomplete
```

you can set it off like this

```
autocomplete="off"
```